# Mostrar imagem abaixo de div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Boa tarde,

Preciso construir um efeito em um blog onde quando você passa o mouse sobre a div rosa, mostra uma imagem que está ao fundo dela. Porém preciso mostrar essa imagem somente na área onde está a fechadura.

O layout é esse aqui. A parte que eu preciso que apareça a imagem é somente no box rosa do topo.

[image: layout]

Basicamente, o ícone de fechadura iria seguir o cursor, e conforme vai mexendo o mouse, vai mostrando a imagem.

Poderiam me ajudar com referências ou um norte de como fazer?

Creio que dê pra fazer isso com jquery ou canvas, talvez até com um pouco de css e js.

A estrutura já está toda montada, só preciso mesmo fazer isso.

Obrigado.

Comment: é como se fosse uma "raspadinha"?

Comment: coloca seu código man

Comment: Isso andrepaulo, mais ou menos isso

Comment: Estarei editando, MagicHat

Comment: A diferença é que a raspadinha ocorre no clique e "apaga" o box que está por cima. Nesse caso eu quero que somente vai mostrando o conteúdo na área da fechadura

Comment: coloca o codigo do seu "cursor" (fechadura) pra gente.

Comment: Segue o código http://codepen.io/leoamrl/pen/KWVmvZ

Comment: tava pesquisando aqui man, acho que talvez com a propriedade `clip-path` do css da pra fazer, mas no IE nao funciona, por ex. :(

Comment: Consegui fazer, dei uma alterada. Se liguem: http://lancamentos.euroamericaconstrutora.com.br/papodecasa/

Comment: posta a resposta ai pra gente ver e ficar pras proximas pessoas com a mesma duvida, voce pode responder sua propria pergunta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver usando uma imagem como "máscara" e um background fixed.
Segue o site:
http://lancamentos.euroamericaconstrutora.com.br/papodecasa/

Comment: Fala Leo Amaral, edita sua resposta colocando o codigo que voce usou, fiquei bem curioso em saber como voce fez.